# Release build not available WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, build, release

I am writing a fairly simple WPF desktop application and under build\configuration manager, release is not an option. The only available options are Debug, New, and Edit.

Anyone have an idea on why this is?

Related: the control library in the same solution does have release as a build option. It is only missing in the wpf app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

To fix i copied the propertygroup tag for release build from the xml in the other project to the project that was missing it.

Answer (score 1):

The propertygroup tag thing does fix the problem.

1) Open your project file in notepad.

2) Paste this after the "debug" propertygroup tag:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```